# How to use a combination of variable and a string in ansible when condition?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to search for a combination of a string and a file in a particular command output and if both exists then skip the task

Here my `data_dir` variable value is `/data/dbdata/test`

```
- name: Extracting existing selinux context
  shell: "semanage fcontext -l -C|grep -i {{data_dir|dirname}}"
  register: selin_context

- name: Setting Selinux context for data and log dir
  command: "semanage fcontext -a -t {{item.name}} {{item.dirpath|dirname}}(/.*)?"
  with_items:
  - { name: 'postgresql_db' , dirpath: "{{data_dir}}" }
  when: "'postgresql_db' and {{data_dir}} not in selin_context.stdout'
```

If i try above then getting below error

```
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: 'postgresql_db' and
{{data_dir}} not in selin_context.stdout
fatal: [pgdbsql-02]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The conditional check ''postgresql_db' and {{data_dir|dirname}} not in selin_context.stdout' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected '/'. String: {% if 'postgresql_db' and /data/dbdata not in selin_context.stdout %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ec2-user/ansible/pgdb/roles/pgdb/tasks/main.yml': line 56, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Setting Selinux context for data and log dir\n  ^ here\n"
```

Please guide me how to handle this?

Comment: Does a contruct like `when: ('postgresql_db' not in selin_context.stdout) and (data_dir not in selin_context.stdout)` will work for you?

Comment: @U880D Yep i think that will work for me.I will try